# R: na.omit in-place for large matrices

Tags: r, performance, memory-management

I have a large matrix `X` (of type `double`) that is about a dozen GB in memory (according to `object.size`). I would like to remove every row in which at least one column is `NA`, i.e., I want `na.omit(X)`. The problem is that

```
X <- na.omit(X)
```

requires approximately twice the memory storage of `X` itself, and two copies of `X` is too big to fit into memory.

Is there way, *maybe using the C API (?)*, to do a `na.omit` "in-place"? Is there a package that implements this behavior?

Comment: I'm not sure you can have anything in-place as you change the dimensions of the matrix.

Comment: you could look into `data.table` package. It has some options to do in place removal.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. So there is no way to resize a vector even in the C API? I’m not against writing my own C extension here. I’ll take a look at data.table’s implementation as well, thanks.